# Asignar valores aleatorios en un rago especifico

Tags: vba, vb, vb6

Tengo declaradas 15 variables (de "A" a "P"), necesito que de manera aleatoria se asignen valores del 1 al 15.

¿De qué manera se podría lograr?

Comment: Porbaste algo? hay funciones para asignar valores aleatorios en todos los lenguajes que nombras.

Comment: Por favor, lee [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) y lee también [Recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) . Te recomiendo que pongas el código que has intentado, y que especifiques los problemas que has tenido.

Comment: Gracias por responder les comparto como logré el código

    
    sub asignar()
    dim a, b, c, d, e
    
    a= Int(15 * Rnd) + 1
    b= Int(15 * Rnd) + 1
    
    do while a = b
    b= Int(15 * Rnd) + 1
    loop
    
    c= Int(15 * Rnd) + 1
    do while a = b or a = c
    c= Int(15 * Rnd) + 1
    loop
    
    
    ' asi hasta completar los 15 numeros aleatorios y diferentes
    
    end



'saludos a todos